# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'movie_id'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'movie_id'
Traceback:
File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender system\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender system\app.py", line 38, in <module>
    names, posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender system\app.py", line 20, in recommend
    movie_id = movies.iloc[i[0]].movie_id
File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender system\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Please help me fix this

```
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import requests

def fetch_poster(movie_id):
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key=8d34d783dcc752ddfc5ef8a4e017f1f4&language=en-US'.format(movie_id))
    data = response.json()
    return "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data['poster_path']


def recommend(movie):
    movie_index = movies[movies['title'] == movie].index[0]
    distances = similarity[movie_index]
    movies_list = sorted(list(enumerate(distances)), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[1:11]

    recommended_movies = []
    recommended_movies_posters = []
    for i in movies_list:
        movie_id = movies.iloc[i[0]].movie_id
        recommended_movies.append(movies.iloc[i[0]].title)
        # fetch poster from API
        recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(movie_id))
    return recommended_movies, recommended_movies_posters


movies_dict = pickle.load(open('movie_dict.pkl','rb'))
movies = pd.DataFrame(movies_dict)

similarity = pickle.load(open('similarity.pkl','rb'))
st.title('Movie Recommender System')

selected_movie_name = st.selectbox(
    'Wanna utilise the time!!!! WATCH MOVIES...',
    movies['title'].values)

if st.button('Show Recommendation'):
    names, posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
```

This code is already tried.